# What Methods Would I Use To Powder Cotton?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

I’m needing a method to turn cotton into a fine powder for use as a source of cellulose. What suggestions would you give to accomplish this with materials/tools that could be obtained at local stores?

Comment: Would a blender followed by using a mortar and pestle grind it fine enough?

Comment: Though the mortar and pestle had come to mind, the blender has been less than successful in application.

Comment: Have you tried shredding it by hand before putting it in the blender? To be honest, your only way to convert fibers into powder is through some sort of mechanical action.

Comment: At least several synthesis procedures I'm aware of and requiring cellulose as starting material use cotton as it is.

Comment: I have hand shredded it, leading me to the conclusion that the blender is still not an effective method. As to the function of whole fibers, the cotton will need to be ball milled for maximum effectiveness in turning cellulose into glucose.

Comment: In a lab I would freeze it in liquid nitrogen (so it becomes brittle) and then use a pestle and mortar or a cooled grinder. Probably not too easy to get liquid nitrogen for home though.

Comment: Re: Liquid nitrogen. You can sometimes get liquid nitrogen for "home use" (e.g. liquid nitrogen ice cream) from a welding supply store. How easy that is depends on your local laws and your local welding supply stores.

Answer (score 1):

The content of cellulose in paper is not as high as that of cotton, however, it may be easier to use as a source if you do require a fine powder. Why do you require cellulose?

Comment: To replicate an experiment in producing glucose. Ref: (http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/cs300845f).